# How to create file named with unicode string

Tags: java, filenames, unicode-string

I want to unzip a file that contains the file named with Unicode string like "\u009F".
I succeeded to output the Unicode-named file as a other name such as "output.zip". But IOException is occurred if I name output file unicode string.

Comment: what is the exact message of the IOException?

Comment: Hey man please read this http://jonisalonen.com/2012/java-and-file-names-with-invalid-characters/ , just like me.